# pass selected row's data to OnContextItemSelected to perform database delete

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So there's a recyclerViewAdapter that populates the data from RoomDB and shows it.
when user long-clicks each row and selects delete,I want to perform a delete query.
How should i retrieve the selected row's data(name or id for example) and receive it in my MainActivity in OnContextItemSelected so that i can delete it from my Db?
-Thanks

```
 private StudentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        numberItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
        imageItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        idItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idView);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);        }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,getAdapterPosition(),"Delete");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,getAdapterPosition(),"Update");
    }
```

MainActivity.java
I've tried many things but couldn't find a clue.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();????
    Log.e(,"info ="+ info);
    Student student = mStudentViewModel.getAllStudents().getValue().get(item.getGroupId());?????
    Student student1 = adapter.getClass().geti?????
    switch (item.getGroupId()){?????
        case 0 :
            break;

        case 1:
              break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to perform a delete query when user swipes the recyclerView by overriding onSwiped!

```
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                                 int direction) {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                S s;
                s= adapterAll.getSAtPosition(position);

                // Delete
                mStudentViewModel.delete(s);

            }
        });
```